# Scaping IFrame inside a HTML page with values loaded using Ajax request

Tags: php, iframe, xpath, web-scraping

I need to scrape this HTML page using PHP ...

```
http://www.cittadellasalute.to.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6786:situazione-pazienti-in-pronto-soccorso&catid=165:pronto-soccorso&Itemid=372
```

... I need to extract the numbers for the rows "Rosso", "Giallo", Verde" and "Bianco" (note that these numbers are dynamic so they can change when you refresh the page but it doesn't matter....).

I've seen that these rows are inside some IFrames (for example ... http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090201 ), and the values are loaded using an ajax request (for examples http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/gtotal.php?id=01090101).

Are there some solutions to scrape directly (I'd like to avoid to parse singular jsons ....), these values from the original HTML page using PHP and $xpath->query?

Suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the values aren't in the original page, they are built once the page is loaded.  So you would need to use something which will honour all the Javascript functionality (i.e. Selinium webdriver) which is a bit overkill for what you want to do (I assume).  Much easier to directly process the IFrame.

You could extract the URL's of the IFrames from the original page ...

```
$url = "http://www.cittadellasalute.to.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6786:situazione-pazienti-in-pronto-soccorso&catid=165:pronto-soccorso&Itemid=372";
$pageContents = file_get_contents($url);
$page = simplexml_load_string($pageContents, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE);

$ns = $page->getDocNamespaces();
$page->registerXPathNamespace('def', array_values($ns)[0]);
$iframes = $page->xpath("//def:iframe");
foreach ( $iframes as $frame )    {
    echo "iframe:".$frame['src'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which gives (just now)

```
iframe:http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101
iframe:http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090201
iframe:http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090301
iframe:http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090302
```

You can then process these pages.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the IFrames code and also that they use a php (for example  http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/gtotal.php?id=01090101), to load values ... I would like to avoid to parse the 4 separate jsons that are returned by php invoke ..... probably it's not possible do it directly ...

Comment: The only way it's possible directly as I mentioned is something which will interpret Javascript.  You may find an alternative, but in the mean time you could solve the problem and move on.